# Databricks how to get output of the Notebook Jobs via API?

Tags: python, databricks

My Python Notebooks log some data into stdout and when I run this notebooks via UI I can see outputs inside cell.

Now I am running Python Notebooks on Databricks via API (`/2.1/jobs/create` and then `/2.1/jobs/run-now`) and would like to get output. I tried both `/2.1/jobs/runs/get` and `/2.1/jobs/runs/get-output` however none of the includes stdout of the Notebook.

Is there any way to access stdour of the Notebook via API?

P.S. I am aware of dbutils.notebook.exit() and will use it, if it will not be possible to get stdout.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? If not how did you solve it?

Comment: @JoãoGaldino we ended with dbutils.notebook.exit(), it still seems like no standard way to read stdout (it might be logical, as it stdout could be huge).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is impossible to get the default return from python code. I saw that on a different cloud provider you can get an output from logs also.
100% solution it is using `dbutils.notebook.exit()`

Comment: dbutils.notebook.exit() seems to consume a lot of time, how can we reduce this turnaround time?